# How to return code to beginning in python

Tags: python

This is my code, and I'm trying to make a code that asks the user if they want to restart the quiz, and if they do, restarts the entire program. It isn't working for me though, and I don't know what's wrong.

```py
first_number = [50, 48, 8, 12, 16]
second_number = [5, 2, 4, 2, 8]
num_problems = len(first_number)
#Start of quiz, gives user prompt to start
print("Hello and welcome to the Math Quiz!")
type = input("Please select one of the following: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, or     Division:")
#Responsible for calulcating all the functions
def calculate(type):
    score = 0
    for i in range(num_problems):
        print(first_number[i], end = " ")
    
        if (type == "Multiplication"):
            print(" * ", end=" ")
            correct = first_number[i] * second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Division"):
            print(" / ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] / second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Addition"):
            print(" + ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] + second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Subtraction"):
            print(" - ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] - second_number[i]
        print(second_number[i])
#prompts user to enter answer
        answer = int(input("Enter your answer:"))
#if user input is correct, will display correct as confirmation
        if answer == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
#if user input is incorrect, will display as confirmation
        else:
            print("Good try!")
        print()
    return score
    return check_again()

#score section, calculates score and gives response based on it
score = calculate(type) * 100 / num_problems
print("You got a: " + str(score) + "%")
if (score == 100):
     print("Amazing!")
if (score == 80):
     print("Good effort!")
if (score == 60):
    print("Keep going!")
if (score <= 40):
    print("Better luck next time!")

def check_again():
    while True:
        again = input("Try again?(Y/N)")
        if again == "Y":
            return calculate(type)
        if again == "N":
            exit()
```

I've already tried to make a return code at the bottom, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You never _call_ the `check_again` function.

Comment: There are so many problems with your code

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should avoid variable names with [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) names such as [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

Comment: You need a major refactoring of your code which you can then wrap in a *while* loop

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason for which it isn't working

First of, part of your code is not inside functions, and therefore is not gonna get executed twice

For instance,

```
score = calculate(type) * 100 / num_problems
print("You got a: " + str(score) + "%")
if (score == 100):
     print("Amazing!")
if (score == 80):
     print("Good effort!")
if (score == 60):
    print("Keep going!")
if (score <= 40):
    print("Better luck next time!")
```

is outside of your

```
def calculate(type):
```

function, so even if you cann calculate(type) again, it will not print it twice

(same goes for type = `input("Please select one of the following: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, or     Division:")` if you wanted to ask the input everytime)

Lastly, you are calling check_again() ( `return check_again()`) after another return

```
return score
return check_again()
```

once you return from a function, you are going out of this function, so the code "return check_again()" is never executed

How you could modify your code for it to work :

Call `check_again()` after `calculate(type)`
move your enbrickment of "if" inside `calculate(type)` function

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because you are returning 2 statements at a time:

Once the program will find the first return it will exit the function

```
return score
return check_again()
```

---

Rather you should call `check_again()` from outside the calculate() function:

```
first_number = [50, 48, 8, 12, 16]
second_number = [5, 2, 4, 2, 8]
num_problems = len(first_number)
#Start of quiz, gives user prompt to start
print("Hello and welcome to the Math Quiz!")
type = input("Please select one of the following: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, or     Division:")
#Responsible for calulcating all the functions
def calculate(type):
    score = 0
    for i in range(num_problems):
        print(first_number[i], end = " ")
    
        if (type == "Multiplication"):
            print(" * ", end=" ")
            correct = first_number[i] * second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Division"):
            print(" / ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] / second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Addition"):
            print(" + ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] + second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Subtraction"):
            print(" - ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] - second_number[i]
        print(second_number[i])
#prompts user to enter answer
        answer = int(input("Enter your answer:"))
#if user input is correct, will display correct as confirmation
        if answer == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
#if user input is incorrect, will display as confirmation
        else:
            print("Good try!")
        print()
    return score



#score section, calculates score and gives response based on it
score = calculate(type) * 100 / num_problems
print("You got a: " + str(score) + "%")
if (score == 100):
     print("Amazing!")
if (score == 80):
     print("Good effort!")
if (score == 60):
    print("Keep going!")
if (score <= 40):
    print("Better luck next time!")
    
def check_again():
    while True:
        again = input("Try again?(Y/N)")
        if again == "Y":
            return calculate(type)
        if again == "N":
            break

check_again()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the functionality in a *while* loop where the user is given the opportunity to select an action or quit. This obviates the need for separate inputs for the action and continuation decision.

You may find this pattern instructive:

```
first_number = [50, 48, 8, 12, 16]
second_number = [5, 2, 4, 2, 8]

assert len(first_number) == len(second_number)

print('Hello and welcome to the Math Quiz')

def calculate(action):
    score = 0
    for x, y in zip(first_number, second_number):
        match action:
            case 'a':
                print(f'{x} + {y}')
                result = x + y
            case 'm':
                print(f'{x} * {y}')
                result = x * y
            case 'd':
                print(f'{x} / {y}')
                result = x / y
            case _:
                print(f'{x} - {y}')
                result = x - y
        if int(input('Enter your answer: ')) == result:
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong!')
    return score

while (action := input('Please select: (A)ddition, (S)ubtraction, (M)ultiplication, (D)ivision or (Q)uit: ').lower()) != 'q':
    if action in 'amsd':
        score = calculate(action) * 100 / len(first_number)
        print(f'You scored {score:.2f}%')
        if score <= 40:
            print('Back to school')
        elif score <= 60:
            print('Below par')
        elif score <= 80:
            print('Not bad')
        else:
            print('Well done')
    else:
        print(f'Invalid selection ({action})')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_number = [50, 48, 8, 12, 16]
second_number = [5, 2, 4, 2, 8]
num_problems = len(first_number)
#Start of quiz, gives user prompt to start
print("Hello and welcome to the Math Quiz!")

#Responsible for calculating all the functions
def calculate():
    type = input("Please select one of the following: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, or Division:") # Bringing it inside func you can also change types. Clearing the screen might help for a better user experience
    score = 0
    for i in range(num_problems):
        print(first_number[i], end = " ")
    
        if (type == "Multiplication"):
            print(" * ", end=" ")
            correct = first_number[i] * second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Division"):
            print(" / ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] / second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Addition"):
            print(" + ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] + second_number[i]
        
        if (type == "Subtraction"):
            print(" - ", end = " ")
            correct = first_number[i] - second_number[i]
        print(second_number[i])
#prompts user to enter answer
        answer = int(input("Enter your answer:"))
#if user input is correct, will display correct as confirmation
        if answer == correct:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
#if user input is incorrect, will display as confirmation
        else:
            print("Good try!")
        print()
    return score   # function exits whenever the return statement is executed
    return check_again() #it will never reach so remove it

#score section, calculates score and gives response based on it
score = calculate() * 100 / num_problems
print("You got a: " + str(score) + "%") #use f strings here
if (score == 100):
     print("Amazing!")
if (score == 80):
     print("Good effort!")
if (score == 60):
    print("Keep going!")
if (score <= 40):
    print("Better luck next time!")

def check_again():
  should_continue = True
  while should_continue:
    again = input("Try again?(Y/N)")
    if again == "Y":
      calculate() 
    elif again == "N":
      should_continue = False

check_again() # Always call the function
```